# How to make div match the height of the containing td?

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have three "panels" laid out along the row of a table. One is taller than the other two and I want all three panels to match the height of the tallest one. I tried styling the divs with height: 100%, but the the short panels stay short, even as the containing tds grow.

My HTML is generated by JSF, so I have limited control over its form, but I can modify the styles. I made a simplified version of the generated code below. The same problem occurs on IE8 and Firefox. However, IE8 renders the short panels vertically aligned to the top of the td, while Firefox renders them in the middle.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Table</title>
    <style TYPE="text/css">
        td {border: 1px solid red; padding: 1px;}
        .panel {border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1px;height:100%}
        .panel-header{background-color: green; color: white;}
        .panel-body {border: 1px solid green; padding: 1px; height:100%;}
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Table</h1>
    <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="panel" style="height:200px;">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    Header One
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Body One
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="panel" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    Header Two
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Body Two
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    Header Three
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    Body Three
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I added a way to do this with jQuery to my post. I hope it helps!

Comment: You can do it with absolute positioning, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33943557/1677209).

Comment: It's five years later, so I can't test against the actual page I was creating then, but just trying out the Fiddle from your, I'm sorry, but it doesn't work at all. You may have misunderstood the problem I was facing. In any case, the jQuery solution Richard suggested worked out just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can set the height to 100% without explicitly stating a height for the tds (or the table). It seems that you have to specify an explicit height on a parent element before `height:100%` will take effect. Perhaps you can modify your styles to be on the td tags themselves instead of the div containers?

If it helps being able to align the divs to the top instead of the middle, I made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/TvbHv/) of how to do it (add `vertical-align:top;` to the td tags). I did an example using only divs too, though I know you said you have limited control over its form.

If you know the maximum height of one element, setting the table or table cells to that height (ie. `height:200px;`) should make the 100% be taken into effect on the divs.

**Edit** If you're not adverse to using jQuery, I have updated my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/TvbHv/1/) to do what you require.

Comment: Drackir is correct; the table TD element does not specify a height value itself, so child elements asking for 100% of the height will not be able to calculate this. As Drackir says, you can manually set the height of the TDs, OR... you can specify the height for them as 100%, specify the height of the DIVs as 100%, and specify the height of the table. OR, you can also apply 100% height to the table as well; the table will take the height value from its parent element, this may not be ideal but it will allow all the divs to be the same height as you add more content to any given DIV.

Comment: Yes, letting whole table grow should work more-or-less when the table only has a single row. However, my real table has several rows. It's a shame that the td elements know how to resize themselves, but can't pass that information down to the divs they contain. I'm going to work on a script that can do the resizing and attach it to the panels' onresize event. If I can get it to work, I'll post it here. (Big if!)

Comment: @Greg Charles: If you're not adverse to using jQuery, I've added an example of what you want to my post.

Comment: No, I'm definitely not adverse to jQuery. It's a godsend! Thanks for putting together that script for me. I'll need a way to limit it to just the row of panels I'm interested in, but I should be able to manage that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Greg Charles: Glad I could help. You just need to modify the selector to include an ID for the container you want. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/TvbHv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
height=100%;   
or
height=inherit;
```

One of these should do the trick :)

Comment: OP already has `height:100%` and says: "I tried styling the divs with height: 100%, but the the short panels stay short, even as the containing tds grow." Also, if these are supposed to be CSS, you'd need to use a colon instead of an equal sign.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question :) But inherit should work then... Or maybe he should style the TD (but that is not what he wants). And yes, you need to use a ':'. But I was typing fast :$ Sorry :)

Comment: I was just letting you know. You can edit your answer to add the colons. :) There's an edit link on the bottom left side of it.

Comment: Yes I know :) But I hadn't seen it :$ 
But youre answer above makes more sense. If there is nothing to inherit, you can't inherit... So you're right! :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/k6Dam/2/

Remove inline-styles (hope you can do that) and set min-height of the panel-body to 200px.

Comment: I think the issue is when the body of one extends past the height of the other bodies. This solution doesn't resolve that see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Drackir/k6Dam/3/).

Comment: @Drackir Sure but with this markup you can't do that without any restrictions. He could maybe read the height of the first element with jQuery/Javascript and set based on the given value the height.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately that may be the only solution. :(