# Set input height 100% of parent

Tags: html, css, input, html-table

I have a little problem with setting input (type text) height to fit 100% of parents (`td`) height. I even tried to iterate through every input and set it height manually with jQuery, but it takes quite a lot of time (site I am working on has a lot of cells) and still doesn't work on IE 7 and 8 (I have to make site work under those too). Here is a sample: http://st8.eu/test.html
It would be greatly appreciated if anybody knows any solution/hack.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot set `height:100%;` on an element if the parent hasn't a set height.

Just set `td { height: 30px; }` and it should work.

Actually, my last link was not working. After a few researches, it seems that you cannot achieve what you want without some JavaScript. But as you said, you tried to use JavaScript, so I assume this should be what you're looking for : [Answer to the same kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4926297/1561269) (Have a look at its fiddle.)
Seemingly, you won't have the choice.

Comment: Can't do it, different TR's have different height in my case.
I do understand percentage needs parent's fixed size, but there must be a workaround.

Comment: Edited again, hope it fills what you want, there doesn't seem to be anything else to achieve what you want.

Comment: Ok so I've set the fixed height of all TD's, looks not as good as it should, but well, limitations :/. Thanks for answer = ).

Comment: Just one thing, why wouldn't you recreate your table with divs, if you really need that output to be like that ?

Comment: I have exactly 699 cells with input inside, it would be really pain in the ass to change it all to divs :P. Besides I'm just a front-end developer, somebody else takes back-end :).

Comment: Well I'm sorry to that. Good luck. But honestly, checking 700 cells in JS shouldn't be too long, I was thinking you were talking of thousand of rows.

Comment: I have to calculate a lot of things that already take some resources, setting height with JS takes about 5 seconds more to load in IE7 and IE8, this is why it's the last thing I should consider :/.

Answer (score 11):

You can set `position:absolute` to the input.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8u1qzLm/) a Fiddle example (note that you must also set a width for the `<td>` that contains the input):

```
input{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    height:100%;
}
td{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
}
```

It works also with `<input type="submit">` and `<div>`.

*Tested on Firefox, Chrome and Edge, For Explorer, you should set a min-height to the input to make it at least usable.*

*UPDATE: For Dracco, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9tay6w10/1/) a Fiddle implementing your example.*

Comment: First of all, it's 2 years old question... Second of all, it's been solved. Hardcoding the TD height is a way to go, though it's not generic. As for position absolute: 1. Positioning table absolute will only be valid if it's practically the only element on the page, or the rest is positioned absolutely as well (otherwise it will mess up the layout of the entire page. 2. Setting position of input as absolute means I have to set the TD as at least relative, and beside of that, it does not change a thing about the height. 3. Did you even consider IE as I mention in question?

Comment: If i have an alternative solution and I think it can be helpful, I post it regardless the age (or the state) of the question. 
1- Absolute positioning isn’t a problem, for example you can put the table in a relative <div> of the same size (it’s one line in js). 
2- I've updated my fiddle setting the <td> positioning to relative, thanks for the hint. 
3- I've tested it and updated my answer.

Comment: Please, be more specific.

Comment: I was specific saying it does not work on multi rows. After your recent change, it still does not work on Internet Explorer, inputs have height of 0.

Comment: The Fiddle I linked yesterday was already multi-row and functioning, but ok... For Explorer read my answer, I 've given a workaround to make it (at least) usable.

Comment: No, the method you used before was setting position absolute on the table element and had just 1 row. Your previous fiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/33eff9eg/ and it has been broken.

Comment: Sorry to write again useless comments, but if you look at edit n.3 (my first edit yesterday), the fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/33eff9eg/1/, and it works! :P

Answer (score 8):

Somehow setting table height to 100% works.

```css
table {
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 1<br> 1 </td>
    <td> <input> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```